# How to set the default value can shown on the table with Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have already created a formClass as below:

```
class LyricForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Lyric 
    fields = ['title', 'body']
    widgets = {
        'body': Textarea(attrs = {'cols': 40, 'rows': 20 })
    }
```

I have used it for create form which I don't want to any default value on that and it works well.

Now I want to inherit it as edit form, whose default value is its existing value like :
[image]

I referenced some relative questions in stackoverflow as below:
views.py

```
def update_lyric(request, pk):
  lyric = get_object_or_404(Lyric, pk = pk)
  form = LyricForm(request.POST, initial = {'title': lyric.title, 'body': lyric.body})
  return render(request, 'update_lyric_page.html',{'pk':pk, 'form':form})
```

But it does not work. There is no any default value shown on the form. How can I do that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using modelforms, you could use:

```
def update_lyric(request, pk):
  lyric = get_object_or_404(Lyric, pk = pk)
  form = LyricForm(request.POST, instance=lyric)
  return render(request, 'update_lyric_page.html',{'pk':pk, 'form':form})
```

Comment: @yobichi glad I could help.